# Getting rid of index.php in codeigniter with Vhost

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I've tried every possible htaccess snippet I could find about this but none will work. My codeigniter projects is found on ci.mydomain.com and I've configured the virtualhost this way

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ci.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias ci.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin x@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/codeigniter
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also set

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I just get 404. What's wrong?
I'm using the latest version 2.1.3

**Update**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [PT]
    ServerName ci.domain.com
    ServerAlias ci.domain.com
    ServerAdmin d@d.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/codeigniter
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried this and it worked for me. Although I would rather use a .htaccess file.

Edit: Guys, the reason I mentioned that I use virtual host is that i suspect that is what causes the problem. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Using a virtual host and a .htaccess is not the same thing. Are you trying to set up the virtual host to use a .htaccess or do you want to do the whole thing in your virtual host?

And, are you sure mod_rewrite is on?

Comment: @Kenzo I'm trying to set up the virtual host to use the .htaccess. Yes It's on, checked with phpinfo()

Answer (score 3):

The actual workhorse for this is a module named `mod_rewrite`, it allows you to set up rewrite rules to redirect urls to index.php for processing.

[See this article for some more in depth details on how to go about this](http://www.fahdmurtaza.com/myblog/2008/08/22/codeigniter-clean-urls-apache-mod-rewrite-removing-indexphp-from-url-in-codeigniter-application.html)

### Update:

It looks like the rewrite conditions you're using are sort of following the old rules.

The two things I think you're missing (one of which isn't relevant, but helpfull) are:

1. `RewriteBase` - I have found specifying a rewrite base goes a long way to helping your rules work better. Technically I think it should work without but I've encountered nothing but problems without it.
2. `RewriteCond` Statements for Excluding actual files - Right now your conditions will mask a lot of real files, which probably isn't what you want.

So how do we fix this?

```
RewriteBase /
```

This will set the root of your rewrite engine to start after the `.com/` this simplifies things because you wont need to deal with the leading /.

As a result you'll need to change your main rewrite rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This will redirect `.com/anything/you/type` to `.com/index.php/anything/you/type` and the php script can pick that up automatically to pass to the router.

This relys on the condition however because otherwise you'd end up in a loop, so above this line you need these conditions to prevent actual files/folders from being hidden:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

With this `!-f` means "Not -f" where -f means "Is A File", the same for -d meaning "Is a Directory" so basically you're saying match this rule only if the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is not a file and is not a directory.

Then any url that points to an actual file will resolve just fine!  (Including index.php).

So with the following lines in your .htaccess you *should* get proper rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

You should be good to go provided you have mod_rewrite enabled in your apache configuration.

If you're using Apache2 on Ubuntu, the command(s) to enable this is trivial:

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 reload
```

It's important the module is actually enabled of all your `Rewrite*` rules in your apache will not execute.

If that still isn't working you need to go check the apache main configuration to see if there's a subset of commands allowed in the .htaccess files, usually an install is set to `All` so that anything can be specified there, but often it's locked down to prevent security overlap between customers. You mentioned you're using a VPS so you probably wont have to do this step, but I thought I would mention it for the sake of others.

The option you'd be looking for looks like this:

```
AllowOverride All
```

There is one last thing that's mainly a saftey net:

Apache offers a way to gaurd clauses against modules existing

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
   ~~ Put Rewrite* Rules here ~~
</IfModule>
```

### Update 2

Ok I just noticed the Virtual host. I think the problem is you're putting the Rewrite conditions in your `<VirtualHost >` block, and they need to exist in the `<Directory>` block for the folder your files are in.

You can do this by removing all `Rewrite*` rules from your conf and either adding this to your .conf file:

```
<Directory /var/www/codeigniter>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

Or adding a `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/codeigniter` with this inside of it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

These rules apply to the directory, not the VHost declaration, and the .htaccess is a shortcut to the `<Directory>` block basically.

**Useful Links**:

- [Apache mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Good link, I'll read through it more  
thoroughly and see. Although it seems like I've done all those steps.

Comment: @MrAzulay I have updated my answer with a more clear explanation of the problem.

Comment: Hmm I am using a VPS, I didn't say that though, I said virtualhost. I'll try allowoverride, otherwise this is stuff you can find everywhere, maybe my question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Did you try the exact rewrite rules in my post? The ones in your update are an old example that I found personally to be more prone to trouble when implementing.

Comment: @MrAzulay I appologize, I missed something fundamental in your question, please check my Update 2 for instructions that will probably help you.

Comment: Big thanks for your effort but the virtual host configuration that I show in my post does work. It's just that i want it in a htaccess-file. But whenever i put exactly those rewriterules in a htaccess file it stops working. I'll try rewritebase but I think I have already.

Comment: Put the `AllowOverride All` directive in the `<Directory /var/www/codeigniter>` block in your .conf it should let .htaccess in that directory be able to do anything you can do in the `<directory ...>` tag.